# how to css link influence only to a "div" card?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a project and use more than 1 template I have problems with 2 css links from 2 different templates, I want the css link from templates to only affect a single html card without affecting the rest in file .cshtml . Please give me a solution.

I have the layout.cshtml file as follows and the css link in my 2nd templates in the last line

```html
<head>
    <title>POU Education Category Bootstrap Responsive website Template | Home :: w3layouts</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="POU Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Android Compatible web template, 
    SmartPhone Compatible web template, free WebDesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, Sony Ericsson, Motorola web design" />
    <script>
        addEventListener("load", function () {
            setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
        }, false);

        function hideURLbar() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Custom Theme files -->
    <link href="~/home/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- shop css -->
    <link href="~/home/css/shop.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="~/home/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- font-awesome icons -->
    <link href="~/home/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- //Custom Theme files -->
    <!-- online-fonts -->
    <!-- logo -->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- titles -->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- body -->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- //online-fonts -->
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/css/style-starter.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

This is an index.cshtml file code that uses the layout above

```html
<!--end post-->
<div class="w3l-homeblock2 py-5">
    <div class="container py-lg-5 py-md-4">
        <!-- block -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3 class="section-title-left mb-4"> Editor's Pick </h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 item">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header p-0 position-relative">
                                <a href="#blog-single.html">
                                    <img class="card-img-bottom d-block radius-image-full"
                                        src="assets/images/image1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body blog-details">
                                <span class="label-blue">Beauty</span>
                                <a href="#blog-single.html" class="blog-desc">The 3 Eyeshadow palettes I own & How to
                                    downsize your stash
                                </a>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur ipsum adipisicing elit. Quis
                                    vitae sit.</p>
                                <div class="author align-items-center mt-3 mb-1">
                                    <img src="assets/images/a1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" />
                                    <ul class="blog-meta">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="author.html">Isabella ava</a> </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="meta-item blog-lesson">
                                            <span class="meta-value"> July 13, 2020 </span>. <span
                                                class="meta-value ml-2"><span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> 1 min</span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-sm-5 mt-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header p-0 position-relative">
                                <a href="#blog-single.html">
                                    <img class="card-img-bottom d-block radius-image-full"
                                        src="assets/images/image2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body blog-details">
                                <span class="label-blue">Fashion</span>
                                <a href="#blog-single.html" class="blog-desc">2 New outfit formulas to add to your
                                    Capsule Wardrobe
                                </a>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur ipsum adipisicing elit. Quis
                                    vitae sit.</p>
                                <div class="author align-items-center mt-3 mb-1">
                                    <img src="assets/images/a2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" />
                                    <ul class="blog-meta">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="author.html">Charlotte mia</a> </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="meta-item blog-lesson">
                                            <span class="meta-value"> July 13, 2020 </span>. <span
                                                class="meta-value ml-2"><span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> 1 min</span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to take the path css at the bottom of the layout.cshtml file (<link href="~/css/style-starter.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">) only affects the card // in the first line (//) but other card components will not be usable  in the index file.cshtml

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: Do include your code.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you got 2-cards in 2-separate-html-files, now you want some global-css to be applied on one, but not in the other html-file or some card contained there.

**Solution-1:**

Add an extra class like `.special-card` and use this class in 1st-file to add CSS to the card selectively, based on this class. Now, when you don't have attach this class in the 2nd card, CSS will NOT be automatically applied there.

**Solution-2:**

In card, where you don't want the CSS to be applied, use **Inline-CSS** adding styles in the html-element directly to **override CSS coming from global-CSS file**.

**Solution-3:**

Keep the CSS that you want to partially apply in some separate `test.css` file, and attach it to only the card (externally), where you want to apply this. Just don't just attach this external .CSS file in your 2nd html file, so it won't take affect.